# PHP Eclipse CTRL-Click for Zend Framework external to project

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework

I have configured my Zend Application and decided to locate my Zend library outside of the application folder so that my libraries could be shared between all my website applications and remove duplicated Zend libraries. For example...

```
-- project1
|  |--application
|  `--public
|--project2
|  |--application
|  `--public
|
`--library
   `--ZendFramework
      |--1.12
      `--1.11
```

I set up my projects to use the particular Zf version required. How do I set this up in eclipse so that the CTRL-clicking will link to the Zend declaration objects when clicked on as well as provide auto-complete?

Tried to use Resource Linking but still doesn't work...
[image: Resource Linking for project]

Comment: Eclipse like probably all IDEs doesn't get its information from your php setup but their own include paths. I don't use Eclipse anymore but there should be the an include paths setting in your project explorer or settings.

Comment: I tried to use linked resources but I still can't hyperlink to declarations.

Comment: I'm talking about include paths not resources. check out this link http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/adding_elements_to_a_project_s_include_path.htm

Answer (score 0):

Project Include path source would not allow inclusion of directories outside of the project and I couldn't figure out to add it as a library so I created a PHP Project for my library files and included it as a project.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but it does now work. Thank you for your comments Adrian.